# How to avoid returning local variable with pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
int* income(int ticket_count, int dailyticket_count) {

    int* p;
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int sum[ticket_count+dailyticket_count+1];
    p = &sum[0];
    int cnt = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < dailyticket_count; ++i) {
        sum[i] = 600;
        cnt++;
    }
    int cnt2 = cnt;
    for (int l = cnt ; l < dailyticket_count+ticket_count; ++l) {
        sum[l] = 1300;
        cnt2++;
    }
    sum[cnt2+1] = 0;
    return p;

}
```

In short and sweet, I would like to return the p pointer which points to the beginning of the sum array.
When I print something like this inside the function:

```
printf("%d",*p) //sum[0]
printf("%d",*p+1) //sum[1]
printf("%d",*p+2) //sum[2]
...
```

It works well inside the function, but as soon as I compile it I get the mentioned warning.

Thanks

Comment: You need to malloc `sum`. Your `malloc(sizeof(int));` is just a memory leak.

Comment: Okay and how can I malloc my array?

Comment: `int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int) * (ticket_count+dailyticket_count+1));` Then use `sum` as if it was an array. At the end of the function `return sum;`

Comment: Also worth reading: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)